# Prevent tab change on PrimeVue TabView component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I am using the TabView component from PrimeVue (Vue 3), and I want to stop the tab change if any changes are made by the user, the problem is that I don't know how. I've already tried passing the event and using **preventDefault** and **stopPropagation** but seems that it doesn't work and click event is still happening.

The procedure should be:

- If any changes are made, user press the tab and a dialog appears.
- If user clicks 'No', I should prevent the tab change and stop the click event

Here is the demo of what I'm trying to archive, should be simple https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-wave-yzl1k?file=/src/App.vue:0-1753

If a flag is true I want to show a confirm dialog and prevent the tab change if user dismiss it.

The component that I'm using for the TabView: https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/tabview

Thanks in advance,

Comment: If you know which tab you don't want to change then disable that tab.

Comment: I want to prevent the change but only if user wants via de confirm dialog when user press the tab, when disabled user can't click and element won't recieve events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue/blob/3.29.1/components/lib/tabview/TabView.vue#L208) it looks like that internally the component will first switch tabs and then emit "tab-click", which explains the issue you're seeing. The exception is if the tab is disabled, in which case it won't change tabs but will emit "tab-click".

It took a bit to figure out, but there is a way to get the functionality you need with only a small adjustment. It requires a change in your `main.js` as well as in your `App.vue` file.

```js
// main.js

/*
 * Put this after you import TabView.
 * This will prevent automatic tab switching but still emits
 * the event to your application.
*/
TabView.methods.onTabClick = function(event, tab, i) {
  this.$emit('tab-click', {
    originalEvent: event,
    tabInfo: tab,
    index: i
  });
}
```

```js
// App.vue

const onTabClick = (event) => {
  if (changes.value) {
    confirm.require({
      message:
        "Are you sure that you want to leave this tab? You'll lose your changes",
      icon: "fal fa-exclamation-triangle",
      acceptLabel: "Yes",
      rejectIcon: "No",
      accept: () => {
        alert("here we should allow tab change");
        activeIndex.value = event.index; // manually set activeIndex
      },
      reject: () => {
        alert("stop tab change");
      },
    });
  }
};
```

These changes modify what the `onTabClick` library method to only emit the event, without automatically switching. Then in your app you can check the `index` property of the event to determine what should be set to active.

When implementing this solution, please be aware that it is not robust against changes to the underlying framework. If you do need a robust component, then you will have to implement a TabView yourself.

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much! Couldn't find a solution and you've saved my day, it is working perfectly! I didnt know that you could overwrite a function outside a component, good to know 

Comment: Happy to help 